# Spock Testing and mocking or stubing database interaction

Tags: unit-testing, grails-orm, grails-2.0, spock

I have a private controller method that is used by multiple actions to retrieve an object from the database.  I can not for the life of me correctly mock/stub the call to the database. The Controller method is:

```
private Order getSalesOrder(){
       def order = Order.get(params.id)
       if(!order){
          flash.message = (code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'order.label', default: 'Order'), params.id])
          redirect action: "list"
          return
       }
       return order
 }
```

The Test method I have at this point is:

```
def "test getSalesOrder returns Sales Order"(){
    given:
    params.id >> 3002L

    criteriaSetup()
    Order testOrder = salesOrders[2]
    Order.metaClass.static.get() >> testOrder

    when:
    def order = controller.getSalesOrder()

    then:
    1 * Order.get(3002) >> testOrder
    //1 * Order.get() >> salesOrders[2]
    order == testOrder

}
```

My results are either a message about too few invocations or I just get a null value back. Both of which cause the test to fail.

I have tried variations of this by using examples found from various blogs or tutorials such as:

```
Order.metaClass.static.get() >> testOrder
Order.metaClass.methods.get = { return testOrder } 
1 * Order.get(3002) >> testOrder
1 * Order.get(params.id) >> testOrder
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, since I'm new to spock tests, Mocking and Stubing in general.  And due to the fact that we are writing test for legacy code it is even more confusing.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly your question is. If you are looking for Mocking and Stubbing explanation then Spock doc is a very good starting point. Check http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1-rc-2/interaction_based_testing.html

Comment: My question is that I want to see that when I call MyDomain.get() it returns an object of MyDomain from the db to render my view, or perform an action on.  And when I run my test the different ways that I've tried to either Mock or Stub that functionality / interaction I get a null value and therefore I can not get my test to pass.  I need to know the proper way of Mocking or Stubbing this interaction because the Spock documentation and / or tutorials don't appear to address this type of interaction(s)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use @Mock([Order]) on top of your test class declaration

Comment: @Mock([Order, SpringSecurityService, User]) are already a part of my declaration.  I'm also using @TestMixin(GroovyPageTestMixin) as well

Comment: I can't see the domain object being created and saved in your test case before you call your controller to get that domain. @Mock will only mock the methods on that class but won't actually create an object. In your given: block try def order = new Order(3002); order.save()  before you call controller.getSalesOrder()

Comment: In the setup() I create an array of Orders.  You'll see it as salesOrders[2] in the testcase

Comment: remove line  Order.metaClass.static.get() >> testOrder and add testOrder.save()

Answer (score 0):

I think your failure case of too few invocations is the correct one. I don't think you can check `1 * Order.get(3002)`. This call will always return 0 invocations, and you would be checking for 1.

You would either have to mock this method with a counter in it to do the count check.